# Passing dictionary values to a function, with missing keys

Tags: python

I have a class with a constructor that receives several arguments. These arguments I get from an external file, which is a list of dictionaries.

My problem is that some dictionaries have missing fields. If a field is missing, I want the constructor to simply receive None instead. But as the code is written now, it exits on an exception.

This is a simple illustration of the situation

```
class Person()
    
    def __init__(self, id, age, name, gender):
        self.id = id
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        

people_list = pickle.load(open("some_file.p", "rb"))
first_person = people_list[0]  # this is a dictionary {'id': '1234', 'age': 27, 'name': 'robert'}
Person(first_person['id'], first_person['age'], first_person['name'], first_person['gender'])
```

As the code is written right now, I get an exception that `'gender'` does not exist as a key in the dictionary, which is true. I want any missing field to gets passed a `None` value, but without doing a billion `if`s or `try .. except`s. Is there a good way to do this? Obviously without still incurring an exception.

Comment: Are you just looking for defaults? `def __init__(self, id=None, age=None, name=None, gender=None)`?

Comment: No. Defaults won't solve the problem that I'm getting an exception when accessing a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Oh...use `first_person.get('id')` it will default to `None`.

Comment: You could simply use `first_person.get("gender")` instead, which returns `None` if a key doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about the .get method that dictionaries have in python. That solves the problem.

Comment: @Mark although the title suggests this is a duplicate of that other question, OP really needs dictionary unpacking here - if anything, this question just suffers from a bad title?

Comment: @Grismar I voted it as a dupe, when they said the comments solved the problem. Perhaps you could give it a better title that will help people find this specific issue. I'd be happy to retract the vote.

Comment: I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can get a value from a `dict` with a default if it doesn't exist with:

```
d = {'a': 1}
print(d.get('b'))  # prints None
```

But in your case, this would be more appropriate:

```
class Person():
    # the defaults are defined in the constructor
    def __init__(self, id, age=None, name=None, gender=None):
        self.id = id
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        

people_list = pickle.load(open("some_file.p", "rb"))
for person in people_list:
    Person(**person)  # assuming they at least all have an 'id'
```

Of course, this only works if the keys of the dictionaries match the names of the parameters exactly.

The `**` operator 'unpacks' the dictionary, so this:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
f(**d)
```

Is the same as:

```
f(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will accept as answer.